# Counting the total number of rows depending on a column value

Tags: oracle

I have a query that should count the total number of rows returned depending on a column value. For example:

[image]

As you can see, the M field should display the total number of rows returned which should be 5 because the FT_LOT are all the same value. Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
VBATCH_ID, MAXIM_PN, BAGNUMBER, FT_LOT
, m 
, level as n
FROM
(
SELECT
VBATCH_ID, MAXIM_PN, BAGNUMBER, FT_LOT, QTY, DC, PRINTDATE, WS_GREEN, WS_PNR, WS_PCN, MSL, BAKETIME, EXPTIME
, una
, dulo
, (dulo - una) + 1 AS m 
FROM
(
SELECT c.containername VBATCH_ID
,pb.productname MAXIM_PN
,bn.wipdatavalue BAGNUMBER
,ln.wipdatavalue FT_LOT 
,aw.wipdatavalue QTY
,DECODE(ln.wipdatavalue,la.attr_081,la.attr_083
,la.attr_085,la.attr_087
,la.attr_089,la.attr_091
,la.attr_093,la.attr_095
,la.attr_097,la.attr_099
,la.attr_101,la.attr_103
,la.attr_105,la.attr_107
,la.attr_109,la.attr_111
,la.attr_113,la.attr_116
,la.attr_117,la.attr_119

) DC

,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') PRINTDATE 
,DECODE(UPPER(la.attr_158),'GREEN','HF',NULL) WS_GREEN 
,DECODE(la.attr_140,NULL,NULL,'PNR') WS_PNR 
,DECODE(la.Attr_080,NULL,NULL,'PCN') WS_PCN 
,p.attr_011 MSL
,P.attr_013 BAKETIME
,p.attr_014 EXPTIME
, CASE
WHEN INSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 THEN
bn.wipdatavalue
ELSE
SUBSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, 1, INSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, '-')-1) 
END AS una
, CASE
WHEN INSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, '-') = 0 THEN
bn.wipdatavalue
ELSE
SUBSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, INSTR(bn.wipdatavalue, '-') + 1)
END AS dulo
FROM Container C
JOIN a_lotattributes la ON c.lotattributesid = la.lotattributesid
JOIN product p ON c.productid=p.productid
JOIN productbase pb ON p.productbaseid=pb.productbaseid
JOIN a_adhocwipdatarecord a ON a.objectrefid=c.containerid
JOIN a_adhocwipdatarecorddetails bn ON a.adhocwipdatarecordid=bn.adhocwipdatarecordid AND bn.wipdatanamename ='TR_BAG_NUMBER'
LEFT JOIN a_adhocwipdatarecorddetails ln ON a.adhocwipdatarecordid=ln.adhocwipdatarecordid AND ln.wipdatanamename ='TR_FT_LOT NUMBER'
LEFT JOIN a_adhocwipdatarecorddetails aw ON A.adhocwipdatarecordid=aw.adhocwipdatarecordid AND aw.wipdatanamename ='TR_FT LOT QTY'
WHERE ln.wipdatavalue = :ftlot AND bn.wipdatavalue LIKE :wip
)
) WHERE level LIKE :n
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m
ORDER BY BAGNUMBER
```

Thanks for helping out guys.

Comment: The magic syntax is GROUP BY.  It's in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066419

Comment: Hello APC, where should I put the group by expression? And what should I group? Right after the ORDER BY line? Thanks APC :)

Comment: @GianIsTheName Could you please re-format the post? It's not clear whether this is supposed to be one giant query or two separate queries?

Comment: Hello Frank, I just realized that now. I have already updated it. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually GROUP BY is not the solution.  Having looked again at your desired output I have realised that what you want is an analytic count.

Your posted query is a bit of a mess and, sorry ,but I'm not prepared to invest time in it.  This is the sort of structure you need:

```
 select vbatch_id, maxim_pn, bagnumber, ft_lot
        , count(*) over (partition by ft_lot) m
 from whatever ...
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407).

Not sure why you need the DISTINCT. DISTINCT almost always indicates a failure to get the WHERE clause right.